# Bootstrap Alerts color saturation

Tags: css, yii, bootstrap-4

Is there a way that I could edit the saturation of bootstrap alert saturation? I'm using Yii framework and I've used the alerts I've noticed the green wasn't green enough I tried looking at the css of the Yii framework, do I add something like this?

```
.alert {  
}
```

In my form code I have something like this that indicates the alert:

```
if($model->request_status == 'On Going!')
        {
            return ['class' => 'info'];
        } else  if($model->request_status == 'Done!')
        {
            return ['class' => 'success'];
        } else if($model->request_status == 'Cancelled!')
        {
            return ['class' => 'danger'];
        } else if($model->request_status == 'High Priority!')
        {
            return ['class' => 'warning'];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override Bootstrap's CSS for [.alert-success](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts) class with your own style.

The default is:

```
color: #3c763d;
background-color: #dff0d8;
border-color: #d6e9c6;
```

Or you can create your own CSS class like `.alert-greener` and use it in your PHP code by replacing `success` with `greener`.

Comment: creating my own css class doesn't work tho I already did that

Comment: Then you should override Bootstrap's CSS like Bizley said:
.alert-success {
    color: #3c763d;
    background-color: #dff0d8;
    border-color: #d6e9c6;
}

(but then with different colors that are 'greener' ofcourse)

Comment: Too bad I cannot find the bootstrap css I'm using Yii2 framework